# Pandas time series analysis - summarising state changes in dataframe / removing redundant dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following (data below is simplified to provide a minimal example):

```
df = 
item state            startTime             endTime
   A     1  2019-05-01 04:30:00 2019-05-02 04:30:00
   A     1  2019-05-02 04:30:00 2019-05-04 04:30:00
   A     1  2019-05-04 04:30:00 2019-05-10 04:30:00
   A     2  2019-05-10 04:30:00 2019-05-12 04:30:00
   A     2  2019-05-12 04:30:00 2019-05-13 04:30:00
   A     1  2019-05-13 04:30:00 2019-05-25 04:30:00
```

Where item A is in state 1 from 2019-05-01 04:30:00 to 2019-05-10 04:30:00, then in state 2 from 2019-05-10 04:30:00 to 2019-05-13 04:30:00, then back to state 1 from 2019-05-13 04:30:00 to 2019-05-25 04:30:00.

I am trying to simplify the dataframe to only have 3 rows that provide the same information, using the startTime from the first occurrence of a state, and then endTime for the last occurrence of that state before switching to a new state.

Here is the result I am going for:

```
df = 
item state            startTime             endTime
   A     1  2019-05-01 04:30:00 2019-05-10 04:30:00
   A     2  2019-05-10 04:30:00 2019-05-13 04:30:00
   A     1  2019-05-13 04:30:00 2019-05-25 04:30:00
```

The actual dataframe I am manipulating may be many thousands of rows long, and so I am hoping to be able to do this operation quickly. Was hoping someone could guide me in the right direction or suggest the pandas operations I am looking for? I am not that new to pandas but have no idea how to approach this and wanted to avoid re-inventing the wheel here...

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `diff` and `cumsum` create the `groupby` key then agg

```
d={'item':'first','state':'first','startTime':'min','endTime':'max'}
df.groupby([df.item,df.state.diff().ne(0).cumsum()]).agg(d)
```